# Central request function in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

While learning Angular, I have seen that some developers create the service with a central request function and wrapper functions for the request methods on top of that. The main argument - this is good for scalability and debugging, however as a beginner I'd like to see particular use cases to understand what advantages has this method got. In general, should it be implemented in any app?

Example of that :

```
constructor(private http: Http, private auth: AuthService) { }

request(url: string, method: RequestMethod, body?: Object) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`);

  const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
    url: `${this.baseUrl}/${url}`,
    method: method,
    headers: headers
  });

  if (body) {
    requestOptions.body = body;
  }

  const request = new Request(requestOptions);

  return this.http.request(request)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((res: Response) => this.onRequestError(res));
}
```

Comment: I guess that's just to ensure the same URL and headers are used for each request. Instead of copying the same code over and over in your application you add it once and use it from everywhere. Otherwise you'd create a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Ok. Is it then an alternative to Interceptors or there is still some specific purpose of using this central request function?

Comment: Interceptors were only added very recently. I don't know what "still some specific purpose" means. It's what I posted above.

Comment: Sorry, I just was not sure if central request function has some other meaning and would do something what Interceptors can't. But in general, I got your point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments Interceptors appeared in 4.3 version, while the "central request function" exists since the beginning of Angular.

> should it be implemented in any app?

Nope. You don't need to implement it at all since it's already implemented as a core Angular [Http](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) service. You may override its methods in your own implementation if you need some additional logic in http-calls. Starting from Angular 4.3 you have an alternative [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) service which serves the same purpose and allows to register Interceptors. So, there are two different core services (the old one and the new one) which give you the possibility to intercept requests and responses globally if you need it. Debugging is not a good reason for that. Global handling of session timeouts is a better example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.